# Nested routes doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

how do i make it work? 
This is an example url i need:

> /name/posts/2

My routes.rb

```
  get "/:name", to: "categories#show" do
    resources :posts, only: [:show]
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app/config/routes.rb**

```
scope path: '/:name' do
  resources :posts, only: [:show]
end

resources :posts, except: [:show]
```

This will pass the `:name` and `:id` params into your `posts#show` function.

**app/controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
def show
  user = User.where(name: params[:name]).first
  @post = Post.where(['id = ? AND user_id = ?', params[:id], user.id])

  render @post
end
```

**NOTE:** This can be more Rails 4 friendly by using Strong Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This will catch anything like `/:name` in the URLs and route it to the categories controller.
Adding `:path => ""` means it will cut the resource identifier from the URL.
So instead of having /`categories/foobar` you now get `/foobar`
Then you just nest your post routes in the parent route.

```
resources :categories, :path => "" do
  resources :posts, :only => :show
end
```

Note that this kind of catch-all route is potentially very error prone as it catches everything, including crap you don't expect:)